# Does the Gauss' Trick Really Belong to Gauss?

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, arithmetic, math-history

We all have heard the story of the young Guass, summing 1 to 100 by writing the sum backward below the original one.

In [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ArithmeticSeries.html) article, just two books are referred for the trick. I looked at both of them but the story was just mentioned briefly without any firsthand reference.

Is this story true and reliable? Is there any good reference proving this?

Thanks.

Comment: Formulas for the sum were known for a very long time before Gauss was born.   Are you asking if the story of school-child Gauss is true as a biographical fact about him?

Comment: no idea how to find out with any reliability. I believed a story about young Milnor for decades. Somebody finally asked him, it turns out it happened to Dantzig some decades earlier; and that is relativley recent.

Comment: There is a part of the story that is usually not told, partly because I made it up. When Gauss showed the teacher the answer, the teacher, irritated at having his rest interrupted, took a very large ruler and $\dots$.

Comment: @zyx Yes, that's what I'm asking for.

Comment: I have seen some article about this question and I think the answer was that there is no definitive information.

Comment: @zyx Would you please tell me how to find these articles, who are their writers or what are their titles, etc.?

Comment: *Does the Gauss' Trick Really Belong to Gauss?* Of course not! That's merely a pious motivational legend mathematicians like to tell their children at bed time, nothing more. I honestly hope you did not actually buy into all that nonsense. I mean, I taught the guy everything he knew, but was too humble to take any credit, that's all! What? You thought Newton discovered calculus after he was hit by an apple falling on his head? Please! I sat down with the man, told him some of the same things I also told that German fellow Leibniz, and then let him write a book about it and take all the credit.

Comment: Somebody compiled a collection of (109!) references to this story, with the earliest being 1933: http://www.sigmaxi.org/amscionline/gauss-snippets.html (Which, for context, is nearly eighty years after Gauss’ death)

Comment: I only remember what I wrote.  If I had more details I would have provided them.

Comment: I have always thought that this feat, whether or not Gauss actually did it, is not incredibly impressive, even for a young child, and does not demonstrate that the person who performs it is a genius.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Brian Hayes, who does the "Computing Science" column for *American Scientist*, wrote about the Gauss legend [in one of his columns](http://www.americanscientist.org/issues/pub/gausss-day-of-reckoning) in 2006.  Brian was particularly interested in variations on the story.  A pdf reprint of the column is available [here](http://bit-player.org/wp-content/extras/bph-publications/AmSci-2006-05-Hayes-Gauss.pdf), and additional material, which he's gathered at his [blog](http://bit-player.org), is available [here](http://bit-player.org/2007/a-mathematical-fable-revisited) and [here](http://bit-player.org/wp-content/extras/gaussfiles/gauss-snippets.html).

It's worth noting that there is no universal agreement as to exactly what problem Gauss is said to have solved, nor the precise means by which he solved it.

Comment: Really?  I've never heard any version of the story other than 'summing the numbers 1 to 100' with the 1+100, 2+99, etc. 'trick'.